# Save result adb command in set /p name= (Bat file)

Tags: android, shell, batch-file, adb

I want to save the result of the `adb` commands below as a variable in my script, but the result is wrong.

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.brand
```

> Output:Samsung

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.model
```

> Output: SM-G920I

```
set /p Brand=adb shell getprop ro.product.brand
set /p Model=adb shell getprop ro.product.model
echo Brand: %Brand% Model: %Model% > Test.txt
```

But the result is:

```
Brand: 0 Model: 0
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: You use a `for /f` loop to parse command output. For a single line output - `for /f "delims=" %A in ('adb shell getprop ro.product.brand') do echo %A`. In a batch script use `%%A` rather than `%A` when typing commands.

Comment: Where do the values `0` come from?

Comment: Thanks for the help
I got the result that I want

Answer (score 1):

With the help given in the comment I got the answer

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('adb shell getprop ro.product.brand') do SET brand=%%A
for /f "delims=" %%B in ('adb shell getprop ro.product.model') do SET model=%%B
echo Marca\Modelo > Test.txt
echo %brand%\%model%  >> Test.txt
```

Answer

```
Marca\Modelo 
samsung\SM-G920I
```